# mongo priority 0 member not being used

Tags: mongodb

Folks,
  We have seen a very strange issue with MongoDB v2.6.9 when slaves with `priority=0` are not being used for read requests and are not returned as part of discovery.  When changing the priority to a non-zero value solves the issue and make these members `discoverable`.

Making the priority a non-zero value is not the desired behavior, as this setting will allow the member to become primary.  These members are in a separate AWS region, and we want to avoid a split-brain situation.

Current Config:  (Notice we prefer the west region to always be primary)

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.config()
{
    "_id" : "rs0",
    "version" : 24,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 7,
            "host" : "west1:27017",
            "priority" : 1000,
            "tags" : {
                "dc" : "west"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : 8,
            "host" : "west2:27017",
            "priority" : 1000,
            "tags" : {
                "dc" : "west"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : 9,
            "host" : "west3:27017",
            "priority" : 1000,
            "tags" : {
                "dc" : "west"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : 10,
            "host" : "east1:27017",
            "votes" : 0,
            "priority" : 2,
            "tags" : {
                "dc" : "east"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : 11,
            "host" : "east2:27017",
            "votes" : 0,
            "priority" : 2,
            "tags" : {
                "dc" : "east"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the 1.4.x NodeJS driver, all reads go to {west} nodes, ignoring the {east} instances.

Comment: Ideally hidden member shouldn't be discoverable, priority should do something with the election only..I see them for two different purposes. Not sure why priority change is making it non-discoverable. Did you check the hidden field of the members.?

Answer (score 1):

Though its strange but I am not sure if it has something to do with the mongo version.
however, looking at your configuration I don't think east member would ever become the primary.
It has lower priority than other members so only one of the west member can become the primary.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/

*Every replica set member has a priority that helps determine its eligibility to become a primary. In an election, the **replica set elects an eligible member with the highest priority value as primary**. By default, all members have a priority of 1 and have an equal chance of becoming primary. In the default, all members also can trigger an election.*

Comment: I updated my question.  We have found a bug in NodeJS MongoDB Driver

Answer (score 0):

We have found a bug in 1.4.38 NodeJS MongoDB Driver and are forking it to fix the issue.  It is ignoring any passive mongodb members.
https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/commits/V1.4.38